# R average counts based on weekdays and weekends

Tags: r

I have the following subset data of my original data.

```
ID    Day
1     Wednesday
2     Wednesday
1     Thursday
1     Friday
1     Saturday
2     Saturday
2     Sunday
1     Monday
```

As you can see ID 1 has one entry on Wednesday. I need to sum up the weekdays for ID 1 and divide by 5. Similarly, I need to sum up the weekend days for ID 1 and divide by 2.

The output that I would need is

```
ID    Weekdays    Weekends
1     0.8         0.5
2     0.2         1
```

As you can see, for ID 1, `Weekdays = 0.8 = (4 entries of ID 1 on weekdays)/5`
Similarly `Weekends = 0.5 = (1 entry on weekends)/2`

What I need to implement is to calculate the average occurrences of each ID on a weekend and on a weekday. I know we can do the functionality with a lot of steps. Is there a way to implement the same with less LOC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could potentially create some short week ends vector and then just do a simple aggregation, here's a possible `data.table` solution

```
indx <- c("Sunday", "Saturday")
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df)[, as.list(table(Day %in% indx)/c(5, 2)), by = ID]
setnames(res, c("ID", "Weekdays", "Weekends"))
#    ID Weekdays Weekends
# 1:  1      0.8      0.5
# 2:  2      0.2      1.0
```